List of report objects in Report Builder 3.0
I have a rectangle within a rectangle that has a visibility formula throwing an error.  There is no way for me to change the sizing so that I can access it.  The error won't let me save the file, so I can't even export it and change the formula manually.  It seems like older versions of Report Builder had a way to select any report object properties from a drop-down menu.  I can't find this drop-down in version 3.0.

I don't use report builder very often (I use Visual Studio) but you should be able to open the .rdl in a decent text editor (VS Code for example) and edit what you need to there such as the size, location etc.

You can click any object(eg. rectangle1) and then press tab or shift+tab to cycle between the report objects.
